# Adding twitter follow button to page via Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter

My Ajax call is generating the following html which creates a twitter follow button and appends it to a div on the page.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/@Model.TwitterName" id='followbutton' class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="true" data-size="medium">Follow @@@Model.TwitterName</a>
```

I can't figure out how to get the twitter widget script to work for appended content.  If the code is there as the DOM is loading then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
twttr.widgets.load()
```

Reloads the script for the html on the page.